# Unity 2019.4 built-in pipeline, Bloom post-process not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've successfully enabled post-processing effects and see them working. But the Bloom effect seems to not be applied to rendering no matter how I change the settings. No error messages are shown. I have light-emitting materials applied to meshes that had worked previously to generate post-processing bloom in Unity 2018.x+. My project is on Unity 2019.4.0f1, built-in pipeline, Mac OS X 10.14.6.

Things I've tried which did not resolve problem:

- Verified that HDR is enabled in graphic settings on all 3 tiers.
- Verified my materials are emitting light at +1 intensity.
- Disabled all other post-proc effects so that only Bloom is applied to rendering.
- Viewing in play time as well as the "Game" view within the editor.
- Adjusting settings of intensity, threshold, fast mode, color on the Bloom effect under Post-Process Volume component. I see no change to rendering for any settings change.
- Tried gamma and linear color spaces.
- Verified that the camera and light-emitting objects are assigned a layer which is used by the Post-Process Volume component.

All of the other articles I've read on this show people fixing the problem by doing one of the things above. But I've run out of knobs to twiddle. How to get bloom working?

[image: rendering example - the rings should have a bloom glow but do not]

[image: camera and material components in the inspector]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot with selected layers on the camera and material settings on the object which is should show bloom effect? And set camera transform to trigger field

Comment: @OnionFan, I added an extra shot that shows relevant components on camera and material. Note that I've disabled all layers other than bloom to simplify the problem. The camera doesn't have a trigger but is global. Tried adding a trigger earlier, but it had no effect. Thank you for your help! If you want to see anything else, just ask.

Comment: To the person that modded my question down... It would be much more helpful if you would describe your problem with the question. I've taken every pain to make it a useful question and follow SO best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my specific problem with a technique that may work for someone else if they've already verified all the other more likely and direct causes of the problem described.

Add a second camera to the scene. Get bloom working for that camera. The second camera does not need to be the main camera. But it can somehow affect the first (main) camera to cause bloom to render on the first camera. I suspect this is a bug in Unity 2019.4.0f1.

Then once you have the first camera working as expected with bloom. Experiment with removing components from the second camera or even deleting the second camera. Reloading the scene or restarting Unity may also change your ability to delete the second camera without causing the first camera to lose the bloom effect.

With annoying trial-and-error along these lines I was eventually able to delete the second camera and have the first camera render with bloom. Something about the second camera's configuration solved a problem with the first camera. It is not a great solution, but it is what worked for me.

Comment: Truly ridiculous, but this is it. This is the Unity Way™, and the only way I've got in Editor viewing of Post Processing reinitialised and running again. Must be done again each time after exiting Play Mode to see Post Processing in Editor.

Answer (score 4):

I check on my project how bloom needs to set, check these things:

- An object on which you want to see a bloom must be on the same layer
  as you set in Post Process Layer - Layers
- Your camera must be on the same layer which are you set in Post
  Process Layer - Layers

[image: Result Screenshot]

[image: Camera settings]

[image: Box settings]

Comment: good suggestion. However, on your advice, I verified the layer/culling settings and they are apparently okay. Also, I know that the layer/culling criteria are working for the object I want to see bloom effect, because I can see other effects like depth of field rendered on that same object when I enable. I've updated my question with these findings. On the bright side, I think we are generating a pretty good list of things to check that could cause this problem.

Comment: I have a very unsatisfying resolution, but I'd like to make sense of it if I can. I added a second camera to the scene along with post-processing volume and layer components and bloom effect. This caused the first camera to show the bloom effect. I played with various combinations with intent to just get one of the two cameras working with bloom and delete the other. But strangely, removing either of the cameras causes the bloom effect not to apply to rendering. Makes zero sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but none of these solutions worked for me, what was only worked was the solution from this video!!
(And of course enabling the Postprocessing in the camera...)

[Post Processing Not Working URP FIX - Unity Quick FIX Tutorial 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3Ao6pKF4AE&ab_channel=VEOdev)

Comment: could you bring the explanation in-line to your answer so that it's not required to browse to the video? That is the StackOverflow convention.